# How to use Butter Knife For Header And Footer for ListView Android

Tags: java, android, butterknife

I add a Header and a Footer to my listview like this:

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_process_person)
            View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_input_forward_department_header, null);
            View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_input_forward_department_footer, null);
            lv.addHeaderView(header);
            lv.addFooterView(footer);
```

And i use view inside header like this:

```
btnForward = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.button_forward);
    btnForward.setText("SetText");
```

How to use ButterKnife Liblary intead of these code? i researched but not resuilt. thank you and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something similar to this example from the ButterKnife docs:

> You can also perform binding on arbitrary objects by supplying your own view root.

```
public class FancyFragment extends Fragment {
  @BindView(R.id.button1) Button button1;
  @BindView(R.id.button2) Button button2;

  @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fancy_fragment, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    // TODO Use fields...
    return view;
  }
}
```

The class which you pass as the first argument to `ButterKnife.bind()` must have fields that are annotated with `@BindView`. The most straightforward way to do this is to create a custom `View` class called `ListViewHeader` or something more specific to your use.

Comment: i cant use my textview, how to do this method? Can you help me solve this?
@BindView(R.id.lv_process_person) ListView lv;
 @BindView(R.id.button_forward) TextView btnForward;

     ButterKnife.bind(this);
        View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_input_forward_department_header, null);
        View footer = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_input_forward_department_footer, null);
        lv.addHeaderView(header);
        lv.addFooterView(footer);
        ButterKnife.bind(lv, header);
        ButterKnife.bind(lv, footer);

Answer (score 1):

This is  a part of my code.Use the view holder patter with static inner class.

```
public class AudioOrderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String TAG = AudioOrderActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    @BindView(R2.id.ib_back)
    RelativeLayout ibBack;
    @BindView(R2.id.tv_title)
    TextView tvTitle;
    @BindView(R2.id.toolBar)
    RelativeLayout toolBar;
    private HeaderViews mHeaderViews;
    private FooterView mFooterViews;
    private View mHeader;
    private View mFooter;

    static class HeaderViews {
        ImageView ivPauseOrStart;
        @BindView(R2.id.iv_previous)
        ImageView ivPrevious;
        @BindView(R2.id.iv_next)
        ImageView ivNext;

        public HeaderViews(View view) {
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        }
    }

    static class FooterView {
        @BindView(R2.id.tv_order_num)
        TextView tvOrderNum;
        @BindView(R2.id.tv_order_transaction_time)
        TextView tvOrderTransactionTime;

        public FooterView(View view) {
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.shop_fragment_audioorder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void init() {
        mHeader = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.shop_layout_head_audio_order_recycler, null);
        mFooter = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.shop_layout_order_detail, null);
        mHeaderViews = new HeaderViews(mHeader);
        mFooterViews = new FooterView(mFooter);
        ButterKnife.bind(headerViews, header);
        ButterKnife.bind(footerViews, footer);
    }
```